# AX2012 C# Interop code similar to FieldNum in X++

Tags: c#, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have some code in X++ that looks like this: `fieldNum(InventDim, configId)`

I need to duplicate this code in C# for an AX2012 Interop program.  I need to do this becuase I need to call the method

`EcoResProductDimensionAttribute::inventDimFieldId2DimensionAttributeRecId(FieldId _inventDimFieldId)`

I know how to make the call in C# but I am completely unsure how to get the FieldId.  I did find an article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc616802.aspx that discusses using the  dll Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services.Client to get access to those specific methods but my AX2012 Environment has no DLL file named Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Services.Client.  Is there some other way to call the above method or a different call to get access to the FieldId?